# jQuery select option by text or value

Tags: jquery

Using Jquery How can I select an option by either its value or text in 1 statement?

```
<select>
   <option value="0">One</option>
   <option value="1">Two</option>
</select>
```

I can do these 2 statements individually but how can I combine the following 2 statements into 1 select OR statement?

```
$('select option[text="Two"]'); //This selects by text

$('select option[value="4"]'); //This selects by value
```

Answer (score 0):

`[text="1"]` will not work for jquery version 1.9+. You need to use `.filter()` to filter out element with condition having text `Two`:

```
 $('select option[value="Two"]').filter(function () { 
       return $(this).text() == "Two";
 }).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) method, and select the option text.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/8sp95tcv/)

```
alert($('select option[value="0"]').text());
alert($('select option:contains(One)').val());
```